# Baking objects always yields a black image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am new to Blender and I am trying to bake some models in order to export them to Unity, but I always get a black image as a result after baking.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/pd0lN0u.png]

Only the land is selected and I haven't connected the image texture node to the diffuse node, since it was like that in the tutorial videos I watched, though it didn't work either when I connected them. I have a sun lamp in the scene.

Used Smart UV unwrap:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uNbMPvS.png]

Comment: your setup seems ok, is your light strong enough? maybe you could share your file?

Comment: Yes here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jko0omnlez1wsv7/AADMhSJvg470jCtLyx4Z7VhDa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You have to recalculate the Normals of your ground, I guess they were messed up: Enter in Edit mode, select all and ctrl N, then Bake again.

Comment: I did this but then when i try to bake again it says unintialised image Land from object Land and it doesn't (tried changing the image but nothing happens)

Comment: As I don't have your Land image in the file you've uploaded, I've created a new image in the UV/Image Editor, then change for this new image in the Image Texture node of the Node Editor, perhaps there's a problem with your Land image and you just have to create a new one?

Comment: Thanks a lot It was a dumb mistake on my part as I didn't specify the proper image in the nodes. Now to figure out how to bake without light